# Issue installing @tensorflow-models/knn-classifier with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow.js

I installed @tensorflow-models/knn-classifier with npm, but when i run it i get an error "Cannot find module '@tensorflow-models/knn-classifier'".
I can see the module under node modules but still i get this error. Other models like @tensorflow-models/mobilenet, @tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder are resolved but not the knn-classifier. Is there something additional needed for this model?

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import * as knnClassifier from '@tensorflow-models/knn-classifier';

const classifier = knnClassifier.create();
const trainData = getTrainingData();
for(const td of trainData) {
   classifier.addExample(td.xs, td.label);    
}
```

Comment: What do you run ? Can you show a bit of your code ?

Comment: @edkeveked added a sample code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now the package is missing `index.js`. Here is the fix

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const knnClassifier = require('./node_modules/@tensorflow-models/knn-classifier/dist/knn-classifier');

const classifier = knnClassifier.create();
console.log('classifier', classifier)
```